# Chave estrangeria não está exibindo corretamente na tela, mesmo com o método __ str __ DJANGO 3.2

Tags: python, django

[image: ERRO]
[image: Código]
Mesmo com o método  colocado na classe CARGO, não está aparecendo como deveria quando mostra na identidade funcionários, como resolver esse problema? obg

Comment: Olá Humberto, boas-vindas ao site. É importante **[edit]** e adicionar **um [mcve] do problema (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)** ([NÃO use imagens para mostrar códigos e logs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635)), com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score -4):

Tente colocar o def **str** fora da classe meta